# SimpleScreenRecorder error: "Can't write header!"

Tags: video, desktop-recording

When I want to make a video, I prefer to use an uncompressed method but it seems to fail. I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Here is what I'm using:

- ogg container
- H.264 Video Codec
- Constant rate factor of 0
- Preset superfast
- Frame skipping allowed
- Uncompressed Audio Codec

But SimpleScreenRecorder outputs this:

```
[PageRecord::StartPage] Starting page ...
[PageRecord::StartPage] Started page.
[PageRecord::StartInput] Starting input ...
[X11Input::Init] Using X11 shared memory.
[X11Input::InputThread] Input thread started.
[PageRecord::StartInput] Started input.
[PulseAudioInput::InputThread] Input thread started.
[PageRecord::StartOutput] Starting output ...
[Muxer::Init] Using format ogv (Ogg Video).
[Muxer::AddStream] Using codec libx264 (libx264 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10).
[VideoEncoder::PrepareStream] Using pixel format nv12.
[BaseEncoder::EncoderThread] Encoder thread started.
[Muxer::AddStream] Using codec pcm_s16le (PCM signed 16-bit little-endian).
[AudioEncoder::PrepareStream] Using sample format s16i.
[Muxer::Start] Error: Can't write header!
[BaseEncoder::EncoderThread] Encoder thread started.
[BaseEncoder::~BaseEncoder] Stopping encoder thread ...
[BaseEncoder::EncoderThread] Encoder thread stopped.
[BaseEncoder::~BaseEncoder] Stopping encoder thread ...
[BaseEncoder::EncoderThread] Encoder thread stopped.
[PageRecord::StartOutput] Error: Something went wrong during initialization.
```

And it doesn't record anything...

I previously had issues to save files but here is something else since it saves me a file but an empty file and my Hard Drive is mostly empty...

The video codec should be compatible with ogg, at least, there are no warnings.

I also tested with a virtual machine with same configuration and it makes the same error.

I wonder how to make it record correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, the ogg container is not compatible with any other codecs than Theora and Vorbis. Even there is no uncompatibility warnings.
Using the regular MKV container works.

If anyone have the same issue, using the MKV container may fix the issue.